# Using Microsoft Graph with client credentials and message subscriptions

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

My goal is to use client credentials and Graph subscriptions for messages, for several users in my tenant.

I'm successfully getting the access token via client credentials, and can use it with Graph for things like creating calendar events for multiple users.

However, when I use the access token to create a Graph subscription for messages, I get a failure of "Unsupported segment type".

Does graph support client credentials for subscriptions? If yes, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users//subscriptions",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "e92caf14-0343-40b0-8720-30946d7fd236",
        "date": "2018-05-17T17:53:34"
    }
}
```

Here's my subscribe function:

```
graph.subscribe = function(token, userid) {

  var subscription = {
    changeType: 'Created',
    notificationUrl: 'my notification url',
    resource: '/users/<userid removed>/messages',
    clientState: 'blah'
  };

  request.post({
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid removed>/subscriptions',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
  }, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('>>> Application error: ' + err);
    } else {
      console.log('>>> Subscription returned ' + body);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `POST` should be issued to the `/v1.0/subscriptions` endpoint, not `/v1.0/users/{upn}/subscriptions`.

You may want to take a look at [this Node.js example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) to see how they're doing it.

Comment: Thank you so much Marc.   It works now.   I have used subscriptions before using user credentials, but when I switched to client credentials I assumed that the endpoint should have the user in the URL, like to does for the createEvent method.   Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you could mark this as answered, I'd appreciate it.